# Redirecting almost all urls that contain a number to one function - Kohana3 framework

Tags: php, kohana, url-routing

I have an action within the controller in Kohana3 framework, everything works fine.

When I type in the url `myconroller/myaction/5` in the browser, it goes to the proper `action_myaction()`, and param `5` can be accessed as `$this->request->param('id);`

**My question is**: how to catch all URLs that looks like
`myconroller/myaction-XXX/5`  (XXX is any number from 1 to 999)
to go to `action_myaction()`?

If I had only several URLs of such type, I would create several actions that call a function by passing XXX as a parameter. 
But what if I have up to 999 possible valid URLs?

Should I modify a bootstrap.php in a proper way? How?
Or, there is another option (if exists)?

Comment: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for my question.  Add the rules for routes in the `bootstrap.php` before the default route:

```
Route::set('xxxroute', 'myconroller/myaction-<param1>/<id>'
array(
    'param1' =>'\d+',
    'id' =>'\d+'
))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' =>'myconroller',
    'action' =>'myaction',
));
```

This way `param1` is a number (else it goes to the default route) and it goes straight to  the action `myaction`.

The parametres could be found there by:

```
$id=$this->request->param('id');
$param1=$this->request->param('param1');
```

Hope this helps to someone else.